# To consider only until hours in time stamp?

Tags: shell

I am trying to call a file which consists of time stamp `%Y%m%d%H%M%S`, and in this, how to consider until hours by excluding minutes and seconds?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon.  You need to clarify your question — ideally, you need to create an MCVE ([MCVE]) which shows what you've tried and what the data looks like.  You also need to explain what you expect as output.  There are simply too many unknowns in this for anyone to be able to answer.  It might be that `sed 's/\([0-9]\{10\)[0-9]\{4\}/\1/g'` does what you need, but it is more likely too enthusiastic.  Which shell are you using, on which platform?  Which commands can be used?

Comment: Hi Jonathan,Thanks for the reply. So, my file name suppose is like xxxxx_201710311409 in which I wanted to consider the file name as xxxxx_2017103114* and the date and time is not hard coded date and time also may vary

Comment: Is the file name a command-line argument, read from a file, entered by the user?  Is it alone on the line or is there other data on the line?  Is there no suffix after the timestamp?  This is why it helps so much to show what you've tried -- we can adapt a solution to your context.  When you don't show what you've tried, we can't guess the context.  However, it is likely that a `sed` script similar to what I outlined previously is what you need to use.  (I see there were typos in my previous edition: `sed 's/\([0-9]\{10\}\)[0-9]\{4\}/\1/g'` (missing a `\}`).)

Comment: The file name looks like abc_abc_abd_abc_abc_201709140926.txt and I want to consider the name abc_abc_abd_abc_abc_2017091409*.txt and the time stamp in the file name vary. Previously when the entire timestamp is not a matter then I used vFile=${vFileName##*/} now I am lost. Here vFileName consists of the location of the file and file name as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many possible ways to map a full file name such as:

```
/some/where/abc_abc_abd_abc_abc_20170914092632.txt
```

(where the name includes the seconds component — 32 in the example) to a name without either the minutes or seconds (or a path prefix).

#### Alternatives using `sed`

Assuming the variable holding name is `vFileName`, then you can use:

```
vFile=${vFileName##*/}   # Remove path prefix
vFile=${vFile%.txt}      # Remove .txt suffix
vFile=$(echo "$vFile" | sed 's/_\([12][8901][0-9][0-9][01][0-9][0-3][0-9][012][0-9]\)[0-9]\{4\}$/_\1/')
```

That makes a fairly serious attempt at semi-validating the date/time string; it requires the first digit of the year is 1 or 2; the second is 8, 9, 0 or 1 (for 18xx, 19xx, 20xx, 21xx), and similarly limits months, days, hours; it then removes the (unvalidated beyond "it must be digits") minutes and seconds.  With the example name, that leaves you with `$vFile` containing:

```
abc_abc_abd_abd_abc_2017091409
```

What you do with it from there is up to you.  You could use a simpler/shorter pattern match (that is less stringent about what it accepts):

```
vFile=$(echo "$vFile" | sed 's/_\([0-9]\{10\}\)[0-9]\{4\}$/_\1/')
```

With the given example data, it produces the same result.

#### Alternatives using only shell

With even less validation, you can get the same result from valid data using:

```
vFile=${vFileName##*/}                       # Remove path prefix
vFile=${vFile%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].txt}      # Remove ####.txt suffix
```

to remove the last 4 digits and the `.txt` suffix.  Since this involves no external commands, it is likely to be quickest. This should work in any reasonably POSIX-compliant shell (Bash, Korn, Dash, Zsh, ...).

Comment: Thank you so much I have used vFile=$(echo $vFileName | sed 's/.\{6\}$//')* and it really worked. I appreciate it Jonathan